# how to connect check_sender_access tables to individual emails in postfix

Tags: email, postfix, mailing-lists

My problem is we have internal email lists managed in postfix and they are open to all internal clients, ie anyone can send to the all@ list, and this has become a problem.  I have looked at the RESTRICTION_CLASS_README and some other docs and I am not seeing how to limit access to individual email lists, email addresses, for check_sender_access.

What I need is "for email all@xyz.com check if you are an authorized sender and reject if not" where I have a separate lookup table for each list that needs this feature, almost all of my email addresses do not need the check, and each one that does needs a seperate list.

Thanks